# Round division to upper integer

Tags: iphone, integer, numbers, rounding

is there a simple way to round the result of a division to upper integer ?

I would like to have this :

```
18/20 -> 1
19/20 -> 1
20/20 -> 1
21/20 -> 2
22/20 -> 2
23/20 -> 2
```

... and so on ...

```
38/20 -> 2
39/20 -> 2
40/20 -> 2
41/20 -> 3
42/20 -> 3
43/20 -> 3
```

Must I manager with NSNumberFormatter stuff ?

I didn't success to get an integer value with that and have an integer comparison to do.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x, y;
int result = (x + (y-1)) / y;
```

testing:

```
    int n = 20;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {         
        NSLog(@"%d+(%d-1) / %d = %d", i, n, n, (i+(n-1))/n);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the standard `ceil()` and `ceilf()` functions available i math.h

Answer (score 0):

Standard C supports `double ceil(double x)` and `long double ceill(long double x)`. Perhaps the iPhone has these available? If your data is in integers in the first place, then you'll either have to find a clever trick or convert your ints to doubles first.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumberFormatter` is used when converting between numbers and strings. In addition to the c functions on primitives mentioned already, you can use `NSDecimalNumber` and `NSDecimalNumberHandler` to perform the calculation and rounding given instances of `NSNumber`. When in doubt, refer to the documentation. [Number and Value Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176-CJBCAGDI)

Sample code to divide, round up to the next integer and display the result.

```
NSDecimalNumber *denominator = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:20] decimalValue]];

NSDecimalNumberHandler *numberHandler = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundUp scale:0 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];

for (NSInteger counter = 1; counter <= 50; counter++) {

    NSDecimalNumber *numerator = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:counter] decimalValue]];

    NSDecimalNumber *result = [[numerator decimalNumberByDividingBy:denominator withBehavior:numberHandler] retain];

    NSLog(@"%@/%@ -> %d", numerator, denominator, [result integerValue]);

    [result release];
}
```